# Select the max Value with subQuery SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the below query, I am selecting the ItemName, Description from `Items` Table and QuantityInStock, CurrentPrice from `ItemsStock` Table. And also trying to fetch the `VendorName` for each Item from `Vendors` Table using `PurchaseInvoices` and `ItemsReceived` Table Relation. Now the problem is I want to fetch the VENDOR who provided the **MOST QUANTITY** for a particular item.

I mean let's say an `ITEM ABC` was provided by 3 VENDORS V1, V2, and V3. V3 provided 90 times (He provided most quantity). Now I want to show him in `VendorName` column. Likewise **for each item show the vendor who provided that item most times.**

**Query I am using (I think this subquery needs to be changed)**

```
SELECT Items.Name
    ,Max(Items.Description) AS Description
    ,Max(ItemsStock.Quantity) AS QuantityInStock
    ,Max(ItemsStock.CurrentPrice) AS CurrentPrice
    ,Max(Vendors.VendorName)
FROM ItemsSold
INNER JOIN Items ON ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = Items.ItemID
INNER JOIN ItemsStock ON ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = ItemsStock.ItemID
INNER JOIN Vendors ON Vendors.VendorID = (
        SELECT max(PI.VendorID)
        FROM ItemReceived IR
        JOIN PurchaseInvoices PI ON IR.PurchaseInvoiceID = PI.PurchaseInvoiceID
        WHERE IR.ItemID = Items.ItemID
        GROUP BY IR.ItemID
        )
GROUP BY Items.Name
```

Comment: do you use MySQL or SQL Server? Because you tagged both.

Comment: @EstebanP. Sql Server !

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags. Please retag the correct RDBMS and **only** the correct RDBMS by editting your question. Thanks.

Comment: sample data please

Comment: What if two or more vendors have the same (highest) quantity delivered?

Comment: @PeterB Good Question actually ! i have not this in mind but select the first one in that case !

Comment: @Hammas_stack2 . . . I don't know how the query *without* the `where` does the right calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Select 
  Items.Name,
  Items.Description,
  ItemsStock.Quantity,
  ItemsStock.CurrentPrice,
  Vendors.VendorName
From 
ItemsSold
INNER Join Items On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = Items.ItemID
INNER JOIN ItemsStock On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = ItemsStock.ItemID
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ItemID ORDER BY sumProvided DESC) rown FROM
  (
    SELECT PI.VendorID, IR.ItemID, SUM(IR.Quantity) as sumProvided
    FROM ItemReceived IR
    INNER JOIN PurchaseInvoices PI on IR.PurchaseInvoiceID = PI.PurchaseInvoiceID
    GROUP BY PI.VendorID, IR.ItemID
  ) a
) v
ON v.ItemID = Items.ItemID AND v.rown = 1
INNER JOIN Vendors ON Vendors.VendorID = v.VendorID
```

Here there's an inner query that sums up the supplies of a particular item by each vendor, then an outer query that numbers the rows with 1 = the highest supplier

In the outermost query we cut it to just the rows that were rown=1 (the most vending vendor

I removed the outer group by because I can't see how it makes sense to aggregate these things. You should note that your question is hard to write a test for, because you haven't included sample data and expected output.. but this is a general tactic for "find the highest X and return other column Y from the same row"

You will have to replace `SUM(PI.PURCHASE_QUANTITY)` with something relevant yourself - you didn't give any clues as to what the structure of the PI table was

I presume that going from v.VendorID to Vender.VendorName will be easy enough for you to do

---

OK, so - debugging SQLs 101

I assert that this should work:

```
Select 
  *
From 
--ItemsSold
--INNER Join Items On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = Items.ItemID
--INNER JOIN ItemsStock On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = ItemsStock.ItemID
--INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ItemID ORDER BY sumProvided DESC) rown FROM
  (
    SELECT PI.VendorID, IR.ItemID, SUM(IR.Quantity) as sumProvided
    FROM ItemReceived IR
    INNER JOIN PurchaseInvoices PI on IR.PurchaseInvoiceID = PI.PurchaseInvoiceID
    GROUP BY PI.VendorID, IR.ItemID
  ) a
) v
--ON v.ItemID = Items.ItemID AND v.rown = 1
```

I just put a SELECT *, then stripped out all the tables apart from one - the one that is doing th most work. So.. **Does it return any records?**

If not, then the join is faulty (there are no records in PI that relate to IR), or there really are no records in PI or IR

Fix it so this returns rows

Next question **Does the query return a 1 in rown column, for the suppliers who shipped you the most of a particular item?**

If not, something is wonky with the records - take a look. If so, we're all good

Join the other tables back in one at a time:

```
Select 
  *
From 
--ItemsSold
/*INNER Join*/ Items /*On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = Items.ItemID*/
--INNER JOIN ItemsStock On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = ItemsStock.ItemID
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ItemID ORDER BY sumProvided DESC) rown FROM
  (
    SELECT PI.VendorID, IR.ItemID, SUM(IR.Quantity) as sumProvided
    FROM ItemReceived IR
    INNER JOIN PurchaseInvoices PI on IR.PurchaseInvoiceID = PI.PurchaseInvoiceID
    GROUP BY PI.VendorID, IR.ItemID
  ) a
) v
ON v.ItemID = Items.ItemID AND v.rown = 1
```

Keep going until you suddenly lose records that you weren't expecting would disappear...

:

```
Select 
  *
From 
ItemsSold
INNER Join Items On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = Items.ItemID
--INNER JOIN ItemsStock On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = ItemsStock.ItemID
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ItemID ORDER BY sumProvided DESC) rown FROM
  (
    SELECT PI.VendorID, IR.ItemID, SUM(IR.Quantity) as sumProvided
    FROM ItemReceived IR
    INNER JOIN PurchaseInvoices PI on IR.PurchaseInvoiceID = PI.PurchaseInvoiceID
    GROUP BY PI.VendorID, IR.ItemID
  ) a
) v
ON v.ItemID = Items.ItemID AND v.rown = 1
```

Maybe all the items in "items sold" and all the items in "items received" don't match up! (Maybe you only ever sold stuff you haven't replaced, or sold things you don't have any purchase records for/existing inventory that is in Items that is received but never sold, or sold but never received)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192263/discussion-on-answer-by-caius-jard-select-the-max-value-with-subquery-sql).

Answer (score 1):

you can simply join with subquery

```
 Select Items.Name,Max(Items.Description) as Description ,
Max(ItemsStock.Quantity) as QuantityInStock,Max(ItemsStock.CurrentPrice)as CurrentPrice,V.VendorName
From ItemsSold
INNER Join Items On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = Items.ItemID
INNER JOIN ItemsStock On ItemsSold.ItemSoldID = ItemsStock.ItemID
INNER JOIN  (
select max(PI.VendorID) VendorID,IR.ItemID
from ItemReceived IR
JOIN PurchaseInvoices PI on IR.PurchaseInvoiceID = PI.PurchaseInvoiceID
group by IR.ItemID
) Vendors ON Vendors.ItemID=Items.ItemID 
join Vendors v on v.VendorID=Vendors.VendorID
Group By Items.Name,V.VendorName
```

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'VendorID'.`

Comment: `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "Items.ItemID" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'VendorName'.
`

Comment: `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "Items.ItemID" could not be bound.`

Comment: you 've used it on your first join , if you dont have such column check your table again and fix it ,

Comment: The column do exist !! `Items.ItemID`

Comment: oh you're right , sorry , i should delete where clause in sub query,

Comment: Yeah thanks alot ! it worked ! but i am a lil confuse ..above solution is also worked and yours also ! but there is some mismatch of data !

Comment: i mean ..your query show different vendor for an item while above solution shows different ! mismatch is for some items !

Comment: Check a specific item and find that

Comment: I have verified results and your query is not returning right result for some reason ! But thanks for putting your effort !